# Disallow Deletion from S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I am wanting to create a S3 bucket that does not allow for the deletion of files.

Does anyone know how I am able to achieve this?

Comment: How does S3 know when you've finished writing?

Comment: @womble - I see a problem in the wording, thanks. I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you mean you want a particular user not to be allowed to delete files? Someone must be able to delete the files.

Comment: @JohnWheal: Not necessarily -- you may want to have a truly append-only bucket.  There are ways around that (like deleting the bucket, or cancelling the AWS account) but for relatively "tamper-proof" backup purposes, I could see it being of some use.

Comment: @womble - that is exactly it. To make a mostly tamper-proof bucket. If it is possible to make an append-only bucket, that is definitely ideal. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can't toggle a flag on a bucket to say "this bucket can never be deleted or its contents deleted", because to be effective, the flag would have to prevent the account owner from doing any of those things -- which would mean you could *never* cancel your account.  Not cool.

However, AWS has the ability to provide limited-permission principals, which can be granted a subset of permissions to an AWS resource.  This is known as "IAM -- Identity and Access Management", and under this scheme the login details for the AWS account itself would be kept under tight lock-and-key (rather than handed out to everyone in the company willy-nilly), and only the restricted credentials would be handed around like a doobie on a teenage camping trip.

I don't have a lot of first-hand experience with IAM and S3, but through a brief dalliance with the [IAM policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html), it would appear to me that a policy that looked something like the following might work:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1344116539061",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1344116519156",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "womble"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd definitely be testing that to make sure it didn't allow anything you don't want it to (for instance, s3:PutObject allows the overwriting of existing objects, which you may not want -- the answer to that is versioning), and you'll still have to learn how to apply the policy (for which the [IAM user guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) or perhaps the [IAM API reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html?r=2678) may be able to assist -- or, if those fail to illuminate, ask a detailed question here and someone may have sufficient IAM fu to be able to point you in the right direction), but at least you've got a pointer in the right direction now.

Comment: For the record, s3:PutObject *does* allow the overwriting of existing objects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592541/amazon-s3-acl-for-read-only-and-write-once-access/10592928#10592928